# Getting node.js output(from Mysql) to Javascript(client-side)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Title says it all I have a freelance project( first one and I promised it would be done by now) and I still can't figure it out. I just want the Name column from my MySQL database (that is being shown on my node.js when I console.log the results) into a JavaScript file. ( I feel like this is a simple solution staring me in the face and I can't figure it out)

```
**CLIENT SIDE** 
var results = ("server.js")
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  {label: "Pop"},
  {label: "Alternative"},
  {label: "Rock"},
  {label: "Jazz"},
  {label: "Hits"},
  {label: "Dance"},
  {label: "Metal"},
  {label: "Experimental"},
  {label: "Rap"},
  {label: "Electronic"},
]);
var edges = new vis.DataSet();

var container = document.getElementById('bubbles');
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};

var options = {
  nodes: {borderWidth:0,shape:"circle",color:{background:'#F92C55', highlight:{background:'#F92C55', border: '#F92C55'}},font:{color:'#fff'}},
  physics: {
    stabilization: false,
    minVelocity:  0.01,
    solver: "repulsion",
    repulsion: {
      nodeDistance: 40
     
    }
  }
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);



// Events
network.on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.nodes.length) {
    var node = nodes.get(e.nodes[0]);
    // Do something
    nodes.update(node);
  }
});

container.on("mouse-wheel", function(event) {
  // prevents zooming with the mouse-wheel event
  event.stopPropagation();
});
console.log (results.name)

**SERVER SIDE** 
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
// var index = require("index.html")
app = express();
app.get('/',(request,response)=>{
    ;
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
    app.use(express.static((__dirname)));
  });
  
  //Binding the server to a port(3000)
  app.listen(3000,()=>console.log("express server started at port 3000"));

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "Nate",
  password: "Black1022!",
  database: "new_schema"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query("SELECT Name FROM test", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    module.exports = result; 

});

});
```

```css
#bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Apple Music Style Bubble UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="bubbles"></div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.js'></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would just remake the whole thing using MVC architecture but I feel like that would take too much time and then I feel like I would be at a loss again anyways.

edit: The "label" part will be replace by the names in the database.
Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: I don't understand what you need can you be more explicit?

Comment: I suggest you learn more about `REST API`. You can't `export` the `result` as a module to the client side.